# Filter elements by optional lists of related elements

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a feeling that I've made things more complex than they need to be - this can't possibly be such a rare case. It seems to me that it should be possible - or perhaps that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

The issue at hand is this: I've declared a database element, `Element`, which consists of about 10 many-to-many relations with other elements, one of which is `Tag`.

I want to enable the user of my application to filter `Element` by all of these relations, some of them or none of them. Say the user wants to see only `Element`s which are related to a certain `Tag`.

To make things even more difficult, the function that will carry out this objective is called from a graphql API, meaning it will recieve ID's instead of ORM objects.

I'm trying to build a resolver in my Python Flask project, using SQLAlchemy, which will provide an interface like so:

```
# graphql request
query getElements {
  getElements(tags:[2, 3] people:[8, 13]) {
    id
  }
}

# graphql response
{
  "data": {
    "getElements": [
      {
        "id": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": "3"
      },
      {
        "id": "8"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I imagine the resolver would look something like this simplified pseudo-code, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pull it off:

```
def get_elements(tags=None, people=None):
  args = {'tags' : tags, 'people' : people}
  if any(args):
    data_elements = DataElement.query.filter_by(this in args) # this is the tricky bit - for each of DataElements related elements, I want to check if its ID is given in the corresponding argument
  else:
    data_elements = DataElement.query.all()
  
  return data_elements
```

Here's a peek at the simplified database model, as requested. DataElement holds a lot of relations like this, and it works perfectly:

```
class DataElement(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'DataElement'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=DataElementTag, back_populates='data_elements')

class Tag(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'Tag'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  data_elements = db.relationship('DataElement', secondary=DataElementTag, back_populates='tags')

DataElementTag = db.Table('DataElementTag',
  db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
  db.Column('data_element_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('DataElement.id')),
  db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Tag.id'))
)
```

Please, ORM wizards and python freaks, I call upon thee!

Comment: Can you add your related database models or DDL?

Comment: @rfkortekaas sure, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it in a rather clunky manner. I suppose there must be a more elegant way to pull this off, and am still holding out for better answers.

I ended up looping over all the given arguments and using `eval()` (not on user input, don't worry) to get the corresponding database model. From there, I was able to grab the `DataElement` object with the many-to-many relationship. My final solutions looks like this:

```
args = {
        'status' : status,
        'person' : people,
        'tag' : tags,
        'event' : events,
        'location' : locations,
        'group' : groups,
        'year' : year
    } # dictionary for args for easier data handling

if any(args.values()):
        final = [] # will contain elements matching criteria

        for key, value in args.items():
            if value:
                model = eval(key.capitalize()) # get ORM model from dictionary key name (eval used on hardcoded string, hence safe)
                for id in value:
                    filter_element = model.query.filter_by(id=id).one_or_none() # get the element in question from db
                    if filter_element:
                        elements = filter_element.data_elements # get data_elements linked to element in question
                        for element in elements:
                            if not element in final: # to avoid duplicates
                                final.append(element)

        return final
```